# SharePoint 2010 and 2013 can't not find SPLimitedWebPartManager

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server, visual-web-part, content-editor-web-part

I trust this is one of the most common question when approaching with adding webpart to you sandbox solution through SharePoint 2010 or SharePoint 2013

I have researched google for a while and can't find any solution to reference.

The problem is I can't find any references to SPLimitedWebParManager as well as  ListViewWebPart, SummaryLinkWebPart, SPWebPartManager, ContentEditorWebPartand the difference in the DLL: Microsoft.SharePoint. in MS Visual studio 2012.

So Does SP2010 and 2013 not support that API?

Answer (score 0):

SPLimitedWebPartManager Class is not available in Sandboxed solution.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.splimitedwebpartmanager(v=office.14).aspx

- Namespace:  Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages
- Assembly:  Microsoft.SharePoint (in Microsoft.SharePoint.dll)
- Available in Sandboxed Solutions: No